# jQuery: filtering a table by text or HTML5 data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, custom-data-attribute

I've got a table with a several columns and rows with an HTML5 `data-attribute`. After reading through quite a few SO questions and answers, I've tried to develop code that will allow live search of a table by text or `data-attribute`, but I'm stuck. **I have gotten the same code to work on `<li>` elements (see that jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stBzc/5/)),** so I think my problem is with my jQuery selectors. Does anyone have suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<input id="search" placeholder="search" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
            California
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Company</td>
        <td>Link</td>
        <td>Notes</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr data-state="california">
      <td>Joe Smith</td>
      <td>Acme</td>
      <td>www.www.com</td>
      <td>n/a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state="california">
      <td>Sue Smith</td>
      <td>Acme</td>
      <td>www.www.com</td>
      <td>n/a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state="california">
      <td>Frank Jones</td>
      <td>Etc</td>
      <td>www.www.com</td>
      <td>n/a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
            Alaska
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state="alaska">
      <td>Sue Henderson</td>
      <td>Acme</td>
      <td>www.com.com</td>
      <td>n/a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-state="alaska">
      <td>Jimmy Dean</td>
      <td>Acme</td>
      <td>www.com.com</td>
      <td>n/a</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("input#search").keyup(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val();
        var regExPattern = "gi";
        var regEx = new RegExp(filter, regExPattern);   
        $("table tr").each(function(){
        if (
        $(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0 &&
        $(this).data('state').search(regEx) < 0 
        ){
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }        
        });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3cvH/17/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 `tr` elements that do not have a `data-state` attribute which you cannot call `.search` on.

You should check if a `data-state` exist before trying to do `.search` on it like this:

```
if($(this).data('state'))
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3cvH/18/)